# I'm running this query on mysql using XAMPP server

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [every derived table must have its own alias](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias)

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT Customer , Count(Customer) AS Reservation FROM Reservation GROUP BY customer) WHERE Reservation>=8 ORDER BY 1;
```

And getting the following error

```
#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias.
```

the same works with MS Access. Appreciate your help in advance, thanks!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [every derived table must have its own alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias), [MYSQL ERROR 1248 (42000): Every derived table must have its own alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3363918/mysql-error-1248-42000-every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias), [I am getting a #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias. I am using a WAMP server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5467801/i-am-getting-a-1248-every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias-i-am-using-a)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Before posting a question here, please do at least a basic search first. The exact error message you posted results in [every derived table must have its own alias](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888779/every-derived-table-must-have-its-own-alias). Searching first reduces clutter caused by duplicate questions and helps keep SO a useful resource. You might want to review the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) before posting any additional questions here, so you'll be familiar with how this site works. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks @WesleyMurch and KenWhite, it works as charm, sorry for the inconvenience caused.I will make sure to check before posting next time. Thank you all for the help!!!

Answer (score 1):

Exactly what the error says, give your derived table an alias, by adding `AS foo` just before the `WHERE`.

Comment: Thanks @Kolink worked perfect!!!

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         Customer , 
         Count(Customer) AS Reservation 
     FROM 
         Reservation 
     GROUP BY 
         customer) AS SOMETABLEALIAS 
WHERE 
    Reservation>=8 
ORDER BY 1;
```

Comment: Whoever downvoted this answer, why did you do that?